# How to scroll a div from left, right, top, bottom without showing the scroll bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried with this...

***HTML***

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="snack-section">
      <ul>
          <li><a><img src="images/demimore.png" alt="MILEY CYRUS DEMIMORE"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/mako.png" alt="MAKO MERMAIDS"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/supernatural.png" alt="SUPERNATURAL"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/labpart.png" alt="THE LAB RATS"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/water.png" alt="JUST ODD WATER"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/scooby.png" alt="SCOOBY-DOO!"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/videogirl.png" alt="VIDEO GIRL"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/heartdixi.png" alt="HART DIXIE"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/jimmy.png" alt="JIMMY NEUTRON"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/expandable.png" alt="EPANDABLES 2"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/demimore.png" alt="MILEY CYRUS DEMIMORE"></a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to scroll the the inside div from all direction. I tried with this but failed...

***CSS***

```
.snack-section{
  position:fixed;
  overflow:auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:500px;
}
```

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: How do you intend to scroll it without scrollbars? Are you intending on providing external controls or are you going for drag n drop?

Comment: @ Darren Crabb .. not exactly the drag and drop. I need that as in the iPhone technology used scrolling with a scrollable view.

Comment: Hmm ok, I'm not sure how to do that ... I think you could look at JQuery mobile perhaps? I've never had much joy with swipe type stuff.

Comment: Try `::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only in mobile devices. In web browsers unfortunately the scrollbars will be visible.

Conversely, While aesthetically it would be nice to not have scrollbars, Users may not know there is content beyond the viewport, and your app/site may become less usable.

There is a possibly hack-y way to achieve this. You can hide the scroll-bar with absolutely positioned divs. Just a rough example, more tweaking maybe needed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="snack-section">
      <ul>
          <li><a><img src="images/demimore.png" alt="MILEY CYRUS DEMIMORE"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/mako.png" alt="MAKO MERMAIDS"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/supernatural.png" alt="SUPERNATURAL"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/labpart.png" alt="THE LAB RATS"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/water.png" alt="JUST ODD WATER"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/scooby.png" alt="SCOOBY-DOO!"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/videogirl.png" alt="VIDEO GIRL"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/heartdixi.png" alt="HART DIXIE"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/jimmy.png" alt="JIMMY NEUTRON"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/expandable.png" alt="EPANDABLES 2"></a></li>
          <li><a><img src="images/demimore.png" alt="MILEY CYRUS DEMIMORE"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
 position:absolute;
 overflow:hidden;
 left:0; right:0;
 height: 500px;
}

.snack-section{
  position:absolute;
  overflow:auto;
  left:0;
  right:-24px;
  padding-right:24px;
  height:500px;
  padding-bottom:24px;
}
```

**Updated**
I noticed in comments above that you intended to use this in iPhones, In that case take a look at [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) it does have settings to hide hScrollbar and vScrollbar